# Add attribute to class using Meteor-Blaze

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

How do I do the below using Meteor + Blaze and/or why won't this work?

Code does/doesn't do what it says below

```
// client...

$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("this logs...");
  $('a.external').each(function () {
    console.log("this doesn't log");
    $(this).attr('title', 'External Link');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Meteor you need to be careful to manipulate your DOM after its drawn. The above code would fire when all the scripts have downloaded, but the DOM hasn't been drawn yet.

Luckily this is super easy!

If your template is this

```
<template name="hello">
    <a href="https://servicelocale.com/" class="external">Link</a>
</template>
```

Then you can use the rendered callback:

```
Template.hello.rendered = function() {
    this.$('a.external').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('title', 'External Link');
    });
}
```

I also used `this.$` instead of `$` in the rendered callback. This is useful because it only looks in the `hello` template instead of all over. So you can have `<a class="external"` on your page, but in a different template, and it wouldn't have the title attribute added.

You can use `$` instead here as well.

Comment: Ok, I believe we've tried this without the `this.$`, but will give it a shot again...

Comment: Cool so this works with template __other than layout__, which means we'll have to write multiple functions for our various templates that need this.  If anyone else has any thoughts on why this won't work for the layout template, please let me know!

Comment: @JohnAllen The layout template is called via `UI.body` so you can use `UI.body.rendered` as per the docs page here (http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_body)